# How do I remove Legacy System Extensions manually?

Tags: plugins

On startup I get the message about Legacy System Extensions. These are for software that is not installed/functional on my machine anymore (with Wacom and Logitech contacting the developer isn't much use) and I wouldn't mind deleting this.

Where do I find these so I can delete them manually?

Comment: If the developer provides an uninstaller, or removal instructions, use that to make sure there's no cruft left over.

But otherwise, just delete the .kext file in /Library/Extensions and reboot.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy. And/or those in /Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions ?

Comment: There and possibly also in `~/Library/`? It would be good to have a list of those here as an answer.

Comment: The Uninstallers from Adobe that are still on my system of course do not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

So using info from the comments and doing this myself.

I used terminal to `cd` into the following directories:

```
/Library/Extensions
/Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions
~/Library/
```

I then ran `grep -ril Logitech *` to find any files related to Logitech repeat for any other offending extension names. e.g. Wacom.

Then removed the corresponding `.kext` files/directories e.g. `sudo rm -rf G13Joystick.kext Logi*.kext`.

I ran `sudo kextcache --clear-staging` to clear the staged extensions

Note: personally I didn't find anything in Library and I didn't have permission to delete things in staged so I followed the information presented in [What is /Library/StagedExtensions for and how to remove extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535279/what-is-library-stagedextensions-for-and-how-to-remove-extensions).

Answer (score 0):

Using the uninstallers is the best method, but that presupposed that you know what you've got!

I would recommend using [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com), which provides you with a detail report about the 'state' of your Mac's system and software. It includes third-part extensions, Launch Agents, and other components that are active in your OS. It even recently alerted me to a computer that still had Silverlight and Adobe PDF browser plug-ins!!